Nuxt3 clears inputs autocomplete
Clear Nuxt3 project. When i do "hard refresh" (cmd+shift+r) there are 3 states of form inputs: Empty, Autocompleted from browser, Empty. Example and code below:
HTML:
<form>
  <input
    v-model="formData.email"
    type="email"
    name="email"
    autocomplete="email"
  />

  <input
    v-model="formData.password"
    type="password"
    name="password"
    autocomplete="password"
  />
</form>

Script:
<script lang="ts" setup>
  const formData = reactive({
  email: '',
  password: ''
});
</script>

If i put form or inputs in <ClientOnly> tag it seem error is gone but i want to use some other solution please.
I expecting that every time i refresh a page autocomplete values will stay in inputs.
Example of behaviour

You missing setup in <script> tag

@DengSihan yes thank you i typed it manually here. On my project it is there ofc
